# How do you unlock a memory card?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard

When I try to delete images from my SD card, I get a message saying "Memory card is locked. Slide lock to "write position."  Where is this lock?

Answer (score 20):

The write-protect lock on an SD card is a very small plastic slider on the side of the card itself. It should be labeled as such, probably in fine print.

[image: sd card]

<sub>(File modified from [original on Wikicommons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SD_Card_1GByte_both_sides_with_scale.jpg) by Afrank99; CC-BY-SA 2.0)</sub>

As you can see from the arrow in the picture, slide down to lock, or up to unlock.

Note that if the switch breaks off, that will leave the card in the locked state. If you can't find anything, that may be what happened.

Comment: If the switch breaks off, cover the lock groove with a stiff tape like duct or electrical so that the entire edge is flush. Depending on the tape it might be fussier than others, but it's saved me in a pinch.