# Need help updating the firmware on my Nikon D700?

Tags: firmware, nikon-d700

I have a Nikon D700 with a firmware level of 1.00A and B.

I want to update this.

I have  Memory card reader. I've inserted a card in the reader and formatted it.

I have downloaded the current firmware 1.04/1.03 and added the bin file to the memory card.

When I plug the card back in the camera, and return to the Firmware version menu, I do not see the update option..

I must be missing something... Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Is the bin file in the root directory of the card?

Comment: I think so. There doesn't appear to be any higher level directory, but there may be something invisible. Do you happen to know what format the card should be. I'm on a mac, but I formatted with FAT32. Thanks

Comment: Format the card with the in-camera option, not a computer

Comment: hmm. I have two cards. Neither one seems to be allowed to be formatted. That option is dimmed. Is there a card lock? (and thanks for helping)

Comment: There's a card lock on the card itself, usually. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50826/how-do-you-unlock-a-memory-card

Comment: these are CF cards, and I can't find a lock...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14947/discussion-between-elendilthetall-and-david-delmonte).

Comment: I got it! I had an MC-36 remote connected. When I unplugged that, I could format and now I'm updating.. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Wow, that's a weird one. Waaaaay down the list of things I would have suggested. Happy updating!

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it.  It may be of use to others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

OK. so I tried everything to format the card, copy the firmware, and update the camera.

It turns out that I had a MC-36 remote control connected. When I detached the remote, I could format the card from the camera, and I could update the firmware. Thanks to all for getting my thinking focused.